# linux development on windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux, vi

We develop C++ code primarily on a  headless linux x64 server with VI. We are provided with windows desktops and I was wondering how others in similar situation work? Do you just use windows to remote into linux box or is there a way to develop on windows.

Two solutions that come to my mind are:

1. Run a linux VM on windows desktop.
2. Cygwin. (not sure about it).

Any others?

Comment: Putty should be a good option.

Comment: What type of version control do you use for development?

Comment: virtualbox with linux installed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [VIM](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) port for windows. As an everyday user I can say that the experience is seamless, except for using windows path separators.

There are other options to consider:

- [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) supplies you with a set of GNU tools compiled natively for windows, including a shell, ssh/scp
- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) gets you a Windows port of gcc.
- [UnxUtilx](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) is another set of GNU tool ports, but with no recent activity.

As others have mentioned, [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) gets you ssh/scp, purpose-built for windows.

Answer (score 1):

The only C++ app I currently develop is Qt based and cross platform so I tend to develop in Windows using Visual Studio and then test on linux. For testing on linux I mostly use putty, vi and make but if I need to use a debugger I use nemiver and xming with putty exporting the x session to the PC for xming to render.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just use windows to remote into linux box or is there a way to develop on windows. -- yes mostly I do that.

winscp is a tool that lets you do your text-editing locally in your editor of choice, whether it be emacs for windows or gedit or notepad, and save remotely.

Answer (score 0):

When I worked in an environment like that, I installed Cygwin/X and putty on my windows box. You use putty to connect to the Linux box with the Connection --> SSH --> X11 --> "Enable X11 forwarding" turned on. You

- Install Cygwin including Cygwin/X http://x.cygwin.com/ — download the installer, make sure the xinit package is selected in the things to install, and hit go!
- Install PuTTY http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ and enable X forwarding in your session settings. PuTTY will automagically set your DISPLAY environment variable correctly.
- Start your X server on Windows (Start -> Programs -> Cygwin/X -> XWin Server ) — you may want to copy this to your Startup group so it runs whenever you log in.
- Use PuTTY to connect to your *nix box and fire up an X Windows program — remember to "amp it off" http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/amp-off.html.

You can use whatever X programs are available on the Linux machine seamlessly on your local client desktop. You can do it with Eclipse or gvim or kate.

Another thing I've had good luck with is using Samba on the Linux box to share my source tree, and then mapping a drive in Windows to that share, using native Windows tools to edit it.